# How to insert fields within headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to insert fields within the headings in a Word document, not before or after them. This is to prepare Word files for import to Madcap Flare which allows file names to be specified within a private Word field. The following code doesn't work because the field is appended before the start of the heading, it needs to be embedded within it. How can I do this.

```
Sub prepareDocForImport()
    Dim headingText As String '  
        With Selection.Find  
         .ClearFormatting  
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
         .Forward = True  
         .Format = True  
         .MatchWildcards = False  
         .Text = ""  
         .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1 ")  
         .Execute  
         While .Found  
             headingText = Selection.Range.Text  
             headingText = Replace(headingText , " ", "_")  
             headingText = LCase(headingText )  
             Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart  
             Set myField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PRIVATE:MADCAP:FILENAME<" & headingText & ">")  
            .Execute  

         Wend
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the cursor one character into the header word.

I also added a line for ensuring that the search starts at the beginning of the document.

```
Sub prepareDocForImport()

    Dim headingText As String
    Dim myfield As Field

    'Moving to beginning of doc in case a different starting point is selected
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory

        With Selection.Find
         .ClearFormatting
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Forward = True
         .Format = True
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .Text = ""
         .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1 ")
         .Execute

         While .Found

             headingText = Selection.Range.Text
             headingText = Replace(headingText, " ", "_")
             headingText = LCase(headingText)
             Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

             'Move seleection one character into the header text
             Selection.MoveRight Count:=1

             Set myfield = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
                                                     Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                                                     Text:="PRIVATE:MADCAP:FILENAME<" & headingText & ">", _
                                                     PreserveFormatting:=True)
             .Execute

         Wend
     End With
End Sub
```